# Python: Outputs none when asked to print

Tags: python

Trying to get the variable compHand and playerHand from their respective functions and printing them in the main function. Outputting none instead of the selected choice

```
def GetCompHand():

    compHand= random.randint(1,3)
    if compHand==1:
        compHand="r"

    elif compHand==2:
        compHand="p"

    elif compHand==3:
        compHand="s"




def GetPlayerHand():

    playerHand= input("Enter r, p, or s:")
    if playerHand.lower() == "r":
       print("You picked rock")
    elif playerHand.lower()=="p":
       print("You picked paper")
    elif playerHand.lower()=="s":
       print("You picked scissors")
    else:
       print("Please enter ONLY r, p, or s")
       return GetPlayerHand()


def main():
    pWins = 0
    cWins = 0
    ties = 0



    compHand=GetCompHand()
    playerHand=GetPlayerHand()

    print(compHand)
    print(playerHand)




main()
```

My question is why is it outputting none twice instead of r,p, or s for either of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some bugs in the code:

1. You had no return statement from the function which would actually return the value from the function
2. You had the definition of the `main` function but it was not invoked from anywhere like

   ```
   if __name__== "__main__":
       main()
   ```
3. you need to import the `random` as well to use it.

Following the modified version of your code which works perfectly now:

```
import random
def GetCompHand():
    compHand= random.randint(1,3)
    if compHand==1:
        compHand="r"

    elif compHand==2:
        compHand="p"

    elif compHand==3:
        compHand="s"
    return compHand




def GetPlayerHand():
    Trueinput=False
    playerHand= input("Enter r, p, or s:")
    while(True):
        if playerHand.lower() == "r":
           print("You picked rock")
           return playerHand
        elif playerHand.lower()=="p":
           print("You picked paper")
           return playerHand
        elif playerHand.lower()=="s":
           print("You picked scissors")
           return playerHand
        else:
           playerHand= input("Please enter ONLY r, p, or s")

def main():
    compHand=GetCompHand()
    playerHand=GetPlayerHand()
    print(compHand)
    print(playerHand)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

let me know if you didn't understand anything. I'll be happy to help you. Thanks

Comment: You technically have an infinite loop, which is fine, but the logic around **Trueinput** should be replaced with **while (True):** or similar, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your functions has a 'return' statement, except for the one case where you recurse back into the same function (which you really should try not to do, btw).  So your functions are returning None because that's what they're defined to do if you don't explicitly tell it to return something.

Looks like you want to add:

```
return compHand
```

at the bottom of your first function, and

```
return playerHand
```

at the bottom of the second

oh...and Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you I knew it was something small I overlooked in my notes. As for the recursion in the function would it be more "correct" to use a while loop to catch the invalid input?